# properties about number of solutions of transcendental equations

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, transcendental-equations

Consider a transcendental equation $f(x)=c$ , where $c$ is a constant and $f(x)$ is a transcendental function whose the radius of convergence of its taylor series is $\infty$ , once it has solutions, does it should have infinitely many solutions (include complex solutions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gives the picture:

If $f$ is an entire function that is not a polynomial then $f$ assumes every complex value, with one exception, an infinite number of times.

(Conway's book on complex analysis)

Comment: This is the Great Picard's Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all: the equation $$e^x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=c$$
has one unique solution for each and every $\,\,c>0\,$

Comment: No, it has infinitely many complex solutions, since the function has period $2\pi i$.

Comment: Either I missed the "including complex solutions" or that wass added later. Thanks